# Adm Zip zipping files as directories

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip, adm-zip

I am trying to pack files into a zip file using Adm-Zip

```
var AdmZip = require('adm-zip');

var pathToZip = 'build/release/Ext.zip';


var zip = new AdmZip();

zip.addLocalFile('background.js');
zip.addLocalFile('chrome_ex_oauth.html');
zip.addLocalFolder('images');
zip.writeZip(pathToZip);
```

However, all the files are getting added as folders inside the zip and the actual content is not getting zipped.

[image: Screenshot]

The Getting Started reference is below and this seems to be a very simple example which is not working as expected. What am I doing wrong?
https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip/wiki/ADM-ZIP-Introduction

Comment: 1.5 yrs later and I am having the same issue...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So I did some digging:
https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip/blob/master/adm-zip.js#L275

addFile is ultimately called by addLocalFile, and that seems to be where the error is occurring, specifically on [line 281](https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip/blob/master/adm-zip.js#L281) where it checks if the ZipEntry is a directory. The wrong flags are getting applied.

To get around this, I ended up calling addFile manually and specified the attributes myself, so that it wouldn't rely on auto-detection and incorrectly flag files as directories.

```
addFile(filePathInArchive, fileBuffer, '', 0644 << 16);
```

To get a fileBuffer yourself, you can use [fs.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback) or [fs.readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options)

Comment: Most files added this way to the ZIP are corrupted.

Comment: Linke to issue on Github: https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip/issues/182

Answer (score 2):

```
var zip = new admZip();
var fs=require('fs-extra');
zip.addFile('NGINX/app.js',fs.readFileSync('./app.js'),'',0644);
zip.writeZip("./files.zip");
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [wiki](https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip/wiki/ADM-ZIP#a3) of adm-zip:

> [void] addLocalFile(String localPath, String zipPath)

Adds a file from the disk to the archive.

> [void] addLocalFolder(String localPath, String zipPath)

Adds a local directory and all its nested files and directories to the archive

As it seems you miss the second parameter that is the zipPath.

Comment: no, I can confirm the OP claim. addLocalFile adds the file as a directory with or without the 2nd argument. I also note that addFile does the same unless  you use 0644 << 16 as the 4th parameter.